# Quillen equivalence of diagram categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, model-categories

Let $C$ be a model category and $B$ a direct category. By Theorem 5.1.3 in Mark Hovey's book *Model categories*, there is a model category structure on the diagram category $C^B$ such that weak equivalences and fibrations are defined pointwise.

Assume that $C\leftrightarrows D$ is a Quillen equivalence. By pointwise application, we obtain a pair of functors $C^B\leftrightarrows D^B$. Is this also a Quillen equivalence?

Comment: (If the question is too basic, please feel free to migrate it over to MSE!)

Comment: I think it follows easily from the definition and from the fact that a cofibrant object in $C^B$ is pointwise cofibrant.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Do we want that fibrant objects in $D^B$ are pointwise fibrant, since the OP write that "weak equivalences and fibrations are defined pointwise"?

Comment: The cofibrations can be defined pointwise if $B$ is inverse rather than direct.

Comment: I'm not saying that pointwise cofibrant diagrams are cofibrant, but that cofibrant diagrams are pointwise cofibrant, see for instance Corollary 15.3.12 in Hirschhorn's book. That's enough, I think.

Comment: Anyway, I've just found out that it is Proposition 15.4.1 in Hirschhorn's book.

Comment: I *swear* I had tried to find it there! It seems strange that he does not check the easier-to-check condition in terms of (trivial) fibrations. In any case, many thanks for your help @Fernando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As Fernando pointed out, the claim can be found in Hirschhorn's book as Proposition 15.4.1.

Here is my own attempt. We write $(F,G)\colon C\leftrightarrows D$ for the given Quillen equivalence and $(F^X,G^X)\colon C^X\leftrightarrows D^X$ for the pointwise induced adjunction. First we check that $(F^X,G^X)$ is a Quillen adjunction. It suffices to show that $G^X$ preserves fibrations and trivial fibrations which is clear because of the pointwise definition of fibrations and weak equivalences. It remains to show that  $(F^X,G^X)$ is a Quillen equivalence, that is, a map $F^X(c^X)\to d^X$ in $D^X$ with $c^X$ cofibrant and $d^X$ fibrant is a weak equivalence if and only if the adjoint map $c^X\to G^X(d^X)$ is a weak equivalence in $C^X$. This follows from the pointwise definition of weak equivalences and fibrations once we know that cofibrant objects in $C^X$ are pointwise cofibrant (which can be shown inductively similarly to the proof of Proposition 6.8 in *DIAGRAM SPACES AND SYMMETRIC SPECTRA* by STEFFEN SAGAVE AND CHRISTIAN SCHLICHTKRULL).

Comment: (If this is correct, then it is easier than I thought.)

Comment: $c^X$ must be cofibrant and $d^X$ fibrant.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Indeed. That's seems to be missing in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen_adjunction).

Comment: (I added it here and on wikipedia.)

Comment: This is why it is relevant that cofibrant diagrams are pointwise cofibrant

Comment: I give an explicit reference for the fact that cofibrant diagrams are pointwise cofibrant in a comment above.

Comment: Right, I missed that too. Sorry for being slow on the uptake. Anyway, now we have everything there...